# Extending CKEditor Plugin functionality

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor with default configuration. I want to extend plugin `image` functionality.

When we click on `image` button it shows a dialog. And there is `url` text box. And I want to give browse button from which we can select a file. And then sending AJAX call it will upload file to server.

I will return file path in JSON and it will fill up URL textbox.

I have tried [dialog API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog), didn't understand how can I edit existing dialogs and add my element.

There is another method `getCurrent`, so I have written function shown below.

```
function getDialog() {
        var current = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
        console.log(current);
    }
```

this will give me full object when I open any dialog (like 'image').
Is this function helpful in anyway ?